# Master database missing (not displayed, at least) in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to set up a login in my DB on Azure and according to all the guides I've seen I need to be logged in to master DB. It's been also mentioned that when I create a server, I get that database "for free" and it's actually called *master*.

I can't see it listed anywhere in the GUI on-line.

So, I've tried to login without specifying what DB I'm choosing (it's optional to do so). Then, I'm logged in, I get new query window and type in *create login...* (because that's what I wish to create) but the triangle to run the query is greyed out.

I'd like to set it up using only the online portal. How can I log on to the master DB and still be able to execute queries? Or, possibly, how can I log on to master DB when I can't see it listed anywhere?

Note, my server has only one database and I've tried to log on to that as well but then an error message when trying to create a login, telling me that I'm not in the master DB.

What am I missing?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The automatically created database *master* isn't listed. One needs to log on to it by explicitly specifying its name. True gotcha.

When you create just `SQL Database Server` and no Database, there will be nothing displayed (unfortunatelly ...). But it is interesting, how come you created a SQL Database Server - just server. Because from the management portal (the HTML5 one, not the old Silverlight) you can't really create just SQL Database Server. The only option you have is SQL Database, which automatically creates server for you, or asks you which one to use if you already have one.

So, I assume that you (a) either have created SQL Database Server from the old portal or via management API, or (b) have create Database actually, which was then deleted. These are the only options to end up having just SQL Database Server and no user databases.

So, you have an Azure SQL Database Server, do you know the name of your server? The web management UI for Master DB will be

`https://[server_name].database.windows.net/?langid=en-us#$database=master`

When you connect you might see some warning message. But you will be able to perform queries successfully.

Comment: You're right spot on. Apparently, the *master* isn't listed. But if you try to log on to it by specifying the name (why haven't I thought of it right away?!) you can get to it. Not intuitive at all. I'll edit your reply to make it much more clear and then I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you *can* create a server without a database. When viewing the SQL Databases tab, look at the top, and you'll see links for DATABASES and SERVERS. Click SERVERS. Then you can hit ADD at the bottom of the screen, where you can create a brand new server with no databases. Here's a [screenshot of the server page](http://sdrv.ms/117seHs) and a [screenshot of the create-server popup](http://sdrv.ms/18gN53k).

Comment: Thanks for the edit Konrad,
@DavidMakogon counter-intuitive UI. But I guess the main reason behind it is to make sure users are focusing on the Database rather than the server.